# Highlight date range in android CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm trying to get Android's `CalendarView` to highligh date ranges, as in this prototype :

[image]

I searched the API doc, and i could not find anything like this, so i tried to implement it mysqelf, but ... the cells containing the days are too small to hold a line, see :

[image]

I can't find a way to connect the lines between two cells. Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: did u get the solution? if yes please share it.

Comment: Nope, i didn't find anything. I ended up creating a CalendarView override and custom views. I don't think i still have access to that code tho, but it's not the end of the world to do, start here : https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html